# Poorly Repaired and Painted Drywall

Tags: patching-drywall, primer

I have a wall in my home that was significantly damaged and poorly repaired. The repaired spots were not sanded properly and have since been painted over multiple times. The result is a wall with many noticeable raised spots. It receives full sun every afternoon so it is entirely cringe-worthy. Aside from applying joint compound or skim coating the entire wall, what are my options?

Comment: Or this? [What's the best way to fix this horrible drywall patch job?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/147768/whats-the-best-way-to-fix-this-horrible-drywall-patch-job)

Comment: Short answer: Nothing. Skimming is the right and only way. It's not difficult and is a great DIY skill for your toolbelt.

Comment: Try sanding with about with 80 grit, or texture the wall.