# How do I fix an unsanded and uneven drywall repair that was painted over?

Tags: painting, sanding, patching-drywall, drywall-mud

Based on the attached pictures, would anyone be able to tell me how I could go about fixing this ceiling imperfection?

I'm doing some renos and learning through mistakes. This time I attempted some drywall repair and then I painted it over, but I did a real poor job this time.

Should I try to sand everything down and start again? Or should I try applying some drywall mud to attempt to blend it into the surrounding ceiling area (with proper sanding and "feathering the edges")

Thanks,

Vlad

[image]
[image]

Comment: See https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/63753/18078

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I repair a poor drywall taping job?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/63753/how-can-i-repair-a-poor-drywall-taping-job)

Comment: Great, thank you for the links