# How can I fix my poor drywall mudding?

Tags: drywall, patching-drywall, sanding, drywall-mud, mudding

So... this was my first attempt at drywalling and I realized a little too late (after painted the first coat of paint/primer) that I did a very poor job.

I'd like to correct this issue and want to figure out the best course of action.

My thought:

- Use 80 Grit Sandpaper to remove paint and as much of the excess mud as I can
- Possibly need to remove the drywall tape and redo it where it was bubbling
- Start the mudding process again, this time using thin layers and feathering it out properly

Thank you.

Here is my disaster:

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you had the sense to stop after one coat, it's not that great a loss, or huge a "disaster." Just a setback. You want harsh lighting while working on it, as well as better technique (and possibly tooling? Do you have a progression of small to large drywall "knives?") See https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/63759/18078

Comment: Thank you for sharing this!

Yes - definitely need to get some better tooling this time around

Comment: I don’t think you need to redo all the tape, you need to cut out the bubbles tape with a sharp utility knife. As to the mudding itself, you’ll have to redo that by sanding it until it’s mostly flat and then feathering out a wider strip of mud.